# How to horizontally center an unordered list of unknown width?

Tags: html, css, centering

It is common to have a set of links in a footer represented in a list, such as:

```
<div id="footer">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want everything inside div#footer to be centered horizontally.  If it was a paragraph, you would just easily say: `p { text-align: center; }`.  Or if I knew the width of the `<ul>` I could just say `#footer ul { width: 400px; margin: 0 auto; }`.

But how do you center the unordered list items without setting a fixed width on the `<ul>`?

EDIT: clarification - the list items should be next to each other, not below.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

The solution, if your list items can be `display: inline` is quite easy:

```
#footer { text-align: center; }
#footer ul { list-style: none; }
#footer ul li { display: inline; }
```

However, many times you must use `display:block` on your `<li>`s.  The following CSS will work, in this case:

```
#footer { width: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
#footer ul { list-style: none; position: relative; float: left; display: block; left: 50%; }
#footer ul li { position: relative; float: left; display: block; right: 50%; }
```

Comment: This is great. Never thought of using display:inline to solve this.

Comment: how about using `display: inline-block` on your `<li>`s? You can center them with text-align and still they'll behave as a block if you need them to.

Answer (score 34):

Use the below css to solve your issue

```
#footer{ text-align:center; height:58px;}
#footer ul {  font-size:11px;}
#footer ul li {display:inline-block;}
```

**Note**: Don't use `float:left` in li. it will make your li to align left.

Answer (score 12):

One more solution:

```
#footer { display:table; margin:0 auto; }
#footer li { display:table-cell; padding: 0px 10px; }
```

Then ul doesn't jump to the next line in case of zooming text.

Comment: I found this one to be the best. Great idea!

Comment: I have returned here to use this a second time, and again it works! Thank you

Comment: This is exactly what i looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

It depends on if you mean the list items are below the previous or to the right of the previous, ie:

```
Home
About
Contact
```

or

```
Home | About | Contact
```

The first one you can do simply with:

```
#wrapper { width:600px; background: yellow; margin: 0 auto; }
#footer ul { text-align: center; list-style-type: none; }
```

The second could be done like this:

```
#wrapper { width:600px; background: yellow; margin: 0 auto; }
#footer ul { text-align: center; list-style-type: none; }
#footer li { display: inline; }
#footer a { padding: 2px 12px; background: orange; text-decoration: none; }
#footer a:hover { background: green; color: yellow; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping the list in a div and give that div the inline property instead of your list.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of philfreo is great, it works perfectly (cross-browser, with IE 7+). Just add my exp for the anchor tag inside li.

```
#footer ul li { display: inline; }
#footer ul li a { padding: 2px 4px; } /* no display: block here */

#footer ul li { position: relative; float: left; display: block; right: 50%; }
#footer ul li a {display: block; left: 0; }
```

Comment: This could have been a comment on the answer that @philfreo gave.