# How to set margin: auto to an unordered list? <ul>

Tags: css

I need to center a `<ul>` element using `margin: 0 auto;`

If I set the width for the ul element (`width:300px`) then its works fine. But I can't do this since it is a dynamic list, then the width changes all the time.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
<ul>
<li>hello</li>
<li>bye</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

`ul{margin:0 auto;}` But it isn't working.

`ul{margin:0 auto;width:300px;}` Works, but I can't set the width in this way.

Comment: To use `margin:0 auto` the width must be fixed. Try with `text-align:center` if you have some text.

Comment: Does this previous question not answer it

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695175/how-to-horizontally-center-an-unordered-list-of-unknown-width?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then write like this:

```
div{
 text-align:center;
}

ul{
 display:inline-block;
 *display:inline; /* For IE7 */
 *zoom:1; /* For IE7 */
 vertical-align:top;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Wg9Dz/

Comment: for me li is not display inline.

Answer (score 0):

rather than that you can use

html

```
<div class = "margin-me">
<ul>
<li>hello</li>
<li>bye</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

css

```
.margin-me, margin-me ul{margin:0 auto;}
```

Comment: Same problem: margin:0 auto; doesn't works if the element has not width defined.

Comment: oho, i didn't thought about that, nice to object :) Thanks @Jaso2970