# HTML center an unordered list

Tags: html, css

I have this code: http://jsfiddle.net/5krBj/

**HTML**

```
<div id="main-nav">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="home.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="vegetables.html">My Stuff</a>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="documentation.html">Log in</a>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="usabilitytest.html">Register</a>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="login.html">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main-nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0 0 0 30px;
    list-style: none;
}
#main-nav ul li {
    float: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 6px;
}
#main-nav ul li a {
    border-left: 1px solid transparent;
    border-right: 1px solid transparent;
    display: block;
    font-size:20px;
    float: left;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 9px 12px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #92CD00;
}
#main-nav ul li a:hover {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px black;
    border: 2px solid #266A2e;
    border-style: outset;
    border-radius: 100%;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -o-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

I am trying to horizontally align this list in the center of the screen.

[I have followed this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695175/how-to-horizontally-center-an-unordered-list-of-unknown-width) but it did not work for me`.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `text-align:center` to the holding `div`:

```
#main-nav{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Then remove the `width` from your `ul` and set `display:inline-block` so that it is effectively treated as textual content, and subject to the centering applied to the parent. Removing the width, means it can be centered according to its 'natural width'

```
#main-nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0 0 0 30px;
    list-style: none;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/5krBj/2/)