# Can't figure how to center the nav bar

Tags: html, css, center, navbar

first time here and I'm also really newbie in HTML/CSS. I just started this project for school and I'm frustrated with this nav bar not being centered. It actually looks centered on my 19 inch monitor but on bigger its more on the left. How do I fix it? Thanks

```css
body {background-color:grey; text-align:center; max-width: 80%; }

header {background-color:white; margin-left:31%; width: 673px}

ul {float: left; width: 100%;  margin-left:20%; margin-top: 1px; margin-bottom: -1px; list-style-type: none; }

a {float: left; width: 96px; text-decoration: none; color: white; background-color: #303030; padding: 3px 9px;
border-right: 1px solid white; border-style: ridge}


.nav { position: relative; left: 0%; }

section {color: #745e4e  ;   text-align: justify; 
width:95%; font-size: 18px; line-height: 90%; word-spacing: 1px; background-color: #FFF4E8
; padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 5px; border-style: solid;
margin-left: 13.5%; 
}

hr {margin-left: -10%; width: 134%; border-style: ridge;}
#arrow {margin:0; position: absolute; left: 16%; top: 29.5%; }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Valve</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text / html; charset = utf-8" />

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <img src="images/valve-logo.png" style="width:700px;height:190px">
  </header>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="history.html">История</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link two</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link three</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link four</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link five</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link six</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link seven</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <section>
    <p>Valve Corporation (позната още като Valve Software или по-кратко Valve) е американска компания за разработване на видеоигри и дистрибуция на дигитални компютърни стоки, базирана в Белвю, Вашингтон, САЩ. Основана е през 1996 г. от бившите служители
      на Microsoft, Гейб Нюъл и Майк Харингтън. Компанията е известна с изключително успешния си и критично аплодиран първи продукт — Half-Life, пуснат през ноември 1998 г. Също така е позната и тяхната социална мрежа за дистрибуция на видеоигри — Steam
      и разработването на Source Engine, използван във всеки техен продукт от 2004 г. насам.
    </p>





  </section>
  </div>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See snippet.

I removed `margin-XXXX` commands, used `margin: 0 auto;` to centralize blocks, corrected `header`'s `width`, removed `padding` from `ul` rule (setting it to zero), changed list elements display to `inline-block`.

The only thing that doesn't change with resize is the header's image width, but I think you can do that if you need.

```css
body {background-color:grey; margin: 0 auto; max-width: 80%; }

header {background-color:white; margin: 0 auto; width: 700px;}

ul {float: left; width: 100%; text-align: center; list-style-type: none; padding: 0;}
 
ul li {display: inline-block;}   
  
a {float: left; width: 96px; text-decoration: none; color: white; background-color: #303030; padding: 3px 9px;
border-right: 1px solid white; border-style: ridge}


.nav { position: relative; left: 0%; }

section {color: #745e4e  ;   text-align: justify; 
font-size: 18px; line-height: 90%; word-spacing: 1px; background-color: #FFF4E8
; padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 5px; border-style: solid;
}

hr {border-style: ridge;}
#arrow {margin:0; position: absolute; left: 16%; top: 29.5%; }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Valve</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text / html; charset = utf-8" />

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <img src="images/valve-logo.png" style="width:700px;height:190px">
  </header>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="history.html">История</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link two</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link three</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link four</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link five</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link six</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link seven</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <section>
    <p>Valve Corporation (позната още като Valve Software или по-кратко Valve) е американска компания за разработване на видеоигри и дистрибуция на дигитални компютърни стоки, базирана в Белвю, Вашингтон, САЩ. Основана е през 1996 г. от бившите служители
      на Microsoft, Гейб Нюъл и Майк Харингтън. Компанията е известна с изключително успешния си и критично аплодиран първи продукт — Half-Life, пуснат през ноември 1998 г. Също така е позната и тяхната социална мрежа за дистрибуция на видеоигри — Steam
      и разработването на Source Engine, използван във всеки техен продукт от 2004 г. насам.
    </p>





  </section>
  </div>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Thanks :) For some reason margin: 0 auto didn't do the job for me before, but you fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this post as a guide: [How to horizontally center an unordered list of unknown width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695175/how-to-horizontally-center-an-unordered-list-of-unknown-width)

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, you could just use the nav tag instead of a list:

```
<nav>
<a href="#" title="#">My Link</a>
</nav>
```

To make sure nav content stays inline, be sure to add comment lines:

```
<nav>
<a href="#" title="#">Test 1</a><!--
--><a href="#" title="#">Test 2</a>
</nav>
```

An example To answer your question:

```
<ul style="width:100%;text-align:center;display:inline">
<li style="width:25%">Stuff</li>
<li style="width:25%">Stuff</li>
<li style="width:25%">Stuff</li>
<li style="width:25%">Stuff</li>
</ul>
```

Telling the UL to 'text align center' tells the elements inside to be centered.

Giving the LI elements an equal width is another story, but you should be able to figure that out, e.g.: No. of links / 100 = x%.

UPDATE:

I realized you wanted to center the navigation bar, not the contents.. my bad.

CSS:

```
ul{ width:500px; margin:0 auto; }
```

EDIT: I had time to make a fiddle, this solves everything; here:

http://jsfiddle.net/scott88/hmaLb5mf/

Comment: Using ul{ width:500px; margin:0 auto; } wrecks the nav bar. I need the nav bar itself centered, but I can't tell because it looks fine on my small monitor. When I send it to a friend he sees it more to the left.