# Centered navigation and sub navigation items in CSS

Tags: html, css, centering, navigationbar

Please, I need some help here.
**How can I horizontally center the items in both navigation bars?**
I have tried everything in my knowledge but could not get the desired result.

http://codepen.io/vichid/pen/cHnmK

HTML:

```
        <nav>
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Item 1</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 7</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Item 2</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 7</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Item 3</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 7</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Item 4</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 7</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Item 5</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 7</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Item 6</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 7</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Item 7</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-item 7</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

CSS:

    @import "compass/css3";

     // Parameters

     $menuColor:#AFF8C4;
     $subMenuColor:#9CE0C9;
     $fontColor: #0E0500;
     $menuWidth:940px;
     $backgroundColor:#FFFCF6;
     $borderRadius:4px;
     $duration:0.33s;

     body{
        background-color:$backgroundColor;
     }
     nav {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%; left: 0; bottom: 50%; right: 0;
     }
     ul.menu{
        width: $menuWidth;
        height: 40px;
        line-height: 40px;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto; 
        padding: auto;
        background-color:$menuColor; 
        @include border-top-radius($borderRadius);

        li{
            float: left;
            width: auto;
            a{
                display: block;
                width: auto;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
        }
        li:hover 
        {
            background-color:$subMenuColor;
            @include transition-property(background-color);
            @include transition-duration($duration);
            @include border-top-radius($borderRadius);

            ul{
                width: $menuWidth;
                background: $subMenuColor;
                visibility: visible; 
                @include opacity(1);
                @include transition-property(opacity);
                @include transition-duration($duration);
                @include border-bottom-radius($borderRadius);
            }
        }
     }

     ul.sub-menu{
        @include opacity(0);
        visibility: hidden;
        display:block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        height: 40px;
        line-height: 40px;
        background-color:$subMenuColor; 
        li:hover{
            @include border-bottom-radius($borderRadius);
        }
     }

     ul.menu,
     ul.sub-menu{
        a{
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            color:$fontColor;
            padding: 0 10px;
        }
     }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to horizontally center an unordered list of unknown width?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695175/how-to-horizontally-center-an-unordered-list-of-unknown-width)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the float left in your `li` tag.  Use the `list-style` and `display` to get the desired display.

```
li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    a{
        display: block;
        width: auto;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
}
```

Preview: https://codepen.io/realhades/pen/jmKZvW

Comment: Thanks a million!

Comment: You are welcome!  If it is satisfactory, please mark the question as answered.