# Centering an unordered list

Tags: html, css

Have an image with a h2 that's centered to it, and want the list below it to also be centered. Been struggling for just over an hour now and don't seem to be getting anywhere with it. Any suggestions?

```css
.images {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 33%;
  /* all ements align to the largest element within the div */
  vertical-align: top;
}

.images ol {
  width: 70%;
}

.images ol li {
  line-height: 1.2em;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
  <h3>Panacotta Vanilla</h3>
  <img src="photo1.png.png">
  <p>recipe ingridients</p>
  <ol>
    <li>Macro free Ranged Chicken</li>
    <li>Cover chicken in almond meal</li>
    <li>Add cayenne pepper, chilli flakes, mixed herbs and paprika</li>
    <li>Cook until all pink of chicken disappears Salad
    </li>

  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to horizontally center an unordered list of unknown width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695175/how-to-horizontally-center-an-unordered-list-of-unknown-width)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the position property of your div to absolute or relative.  Then you should be able to position it.  Then use margin: auto to put it in center.

```
position: relative;
margin: auto;
```

Adding this to your your css or

```
position: absolute;
left: 400px; //<!--Change this to position it manually-->
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks :) mind explaining to me why the positioning needs to be relative in order to do this? thanks!

Comment: setting your position to relative tells the browser that this element will be moved and positioned based on where it would have been as regular html.  Position absolute tell the browser that your element will be position from the top left corner.  

Im a rookie myself and still figuring all this stuff out.

Good luck

Comment: Please correct me instead of downvoting me people, Id love to know a better solution.

Comment: I didn't downvote you but I'll chip in anyway. I believe the absolute-position leads to more work later on. If you change the width of either the content or the parent later on you'll have to manually re-position the content every time. (There has also been the mindset that absolute positioned divs is bad SEO, but that is likely not true anymore since the shift to headless crawlers over pure scraping bots - if the google-bot sees your div on the page it likely doesn't matter if it's absolute or not.) I think the inline-block solution is ok, but personally I'd go with a flex-box solution here.

Comment: Thats good to know.  I have actually never used the flex settings and will definitely look into learning them.

Answer (score 1):

Run this in full page view for best results.

```css
.images{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    width:33%;
    /* all ements align to the largest element within the div */
    vertical-align:top;

   
}

.images ol{
    margin-left:auto;width:100%;margin-right:auto;
}
.images ol li{
  text-align:left;
  margin-left:15%;margin-right:20%;
  line-height:1.2em;
  border:0;

}
```

```html
<div class = "images">
  <h3>Panacotta Vanilla</h3>
    <img src = "photo1.png.png">
    <p>recipe ingridients</p>
    <ol id="mylist">
     <li>Macro free Ranged Chicken</li>
     <li>Cover chicken in almond meal</li>
     <li>Add cayenne pepper, chilli flakes, mixed herbs and paprika</li>
     <li>Cook until all pink of chicken disappears 
     Salad</li>

    </ol>
  </div>
```